# how to fix : "RNCSafeprovider was not found in UIManager on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

whenever I try to code navigation /try wrapping up with Navigation container I'm facing this issue of **"RNCSafeprovider was not found in UIManager**. Due to which I'm unable to implement the react-navigation in my application.

any such help or solution would be appreciated as I'm stuck in the middle of the project.

[please click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tay4O.png)

```
    import  React,{ Component} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {styles} from './styles';
import Home from './Home';
import Deployment from './Deployment';
import Header from './Header';



const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to run the following commands:

```
npm install react-native-safe-area-context

react-native link react-native-safe-area-context
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did the following to resolve this issue:
1. npm install --save-dev react-native-safe-area-context  
2. react-native link react-native-safe-area-context

(--save-dev / --save key word makes sure update the package.json file which will help us avoid any errors during the linking operation in 2nd step)